# Showing fields of related m2o objects in django-admin

Tags: python, django, orm, django-admin

I have model Job which is shown using modelAdmin.
And also I have stop model:

```
class Stop(models.Model):
    ...
    job = models.ForeignKey(to=Job, ...)
    stop_number = ...
    ...
```

Job can have from 2 to 3 stops.

I've tried to show first and second stop names using:

```
@admin.register(Job)
class JobAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def stop_1(self, obj):
        stop = self.stop_set.objects.get(stop_number=1)
        return stop.name

    def stop_2(self, obj):
        stop = self.stop_set.objects.get(stop_number=2)
        return stop.name

    list_display = ('stop_1', 'stop_2', ...)
```

But it does many SQL queries on each list view rendering and makes it way too slow. Is there a way to query needed info in single or just few queries?

Comment: I guess there should be something about overriding get_queryset method and aggregating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `prefetch_related` to `get_queryset` to prefetch the objects in one query and reduce the number of queries.

A couple more points:

- `stop_set` is a queryset, you can call `.get()` on it without `objects`
- You want to get `stop_set` off `obj` not `self`. `obj`, is the `Job` object, which will refer to a row in the list display. `self` is the `JobAdmin` class.

```py
@admin.register(Job)
class JobAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('stop_set')
        return qs

    def stop_1(self, obj):
        stop = obj.stop_set.get(stop_number=1)
        return stop.name

    def stop_2(self, obj):
        stop = obj.stop_set.get(stop_number=2)
        return stop.name

    list_display = ('stop_1', 'stop_2', ...)
```